# `bower install --config.interactive=false` npm ERR! Exit status 1

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower, meanjs

I am installing meanjs full stack express, angularjs frameworkf and I get following error

```
npm ERR! meanjs@0.3.3 postinstall: `bower install --config.interactive=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meanjs@0.3.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the meanjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install --config.interactive=false
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meanjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/pickingotest/pickingo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.26
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/pickingotest/pickingo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

My package.json contains following

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
},
```

Comment: Can you run `bower install` (i.e. *without* the `--config.interactive` option) and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on a brand new ubuntu server. The error message was really misleading and I found that the problem was with the nodejs interpreter.

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

And after that "yo meanjs" worked like a charm.

Hope it helps

Comment: No it didnt work. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-legacy : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Strange I seem to be having same issue. npm WARN cannot run in wd angular-seed@0.0.0 bower install

Comment: Hi, I'm costel. You mentioned it in Ubuntu. But how to fix it in windows?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a package dependencies conflict then use *resolutions* in the **Bower.json**. i added a longer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686419/error-with-npm-install-failed-at-the-meanjs0-3-3-postinstall-script/28384758#28384758)

Comment: Gosh, did you even examine the link? It's a stack overflow answer!